# connect for 2 Databases

Tags: php, database, oop

There is a problem with a connection to DB.

Used class for DB

```
class DB
{
    public static $connect = false;
    private $database_host = 'localhost';
    private $database_user = '';
    private $database_pass = '';
    private $database_db = '';
    private $database_type = 'mysql';

    function __construct($database_host, $database_db, $database_user, $database_pass)
    {
        $this->database_host   = $database_host;
        $this->database_db     = $database_db;
        $this->database_user   = $database_user;
        $this->database_pass   = $database_pass;

        if (self::$connect === false) {
            $this->connect();
        }
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $dsn = $this->database_type . ":dbname=" . $this->database_db . ";host=" . $this->database_host;

        try {

            self::$connect = new PDO($dsn, $this->database_user, $this->database_pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
            self::$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            //var_dump(self::$connect);

            if(!self::$connect) {
            die("Cannot connect to DB");    
            }


        } catch (PDOException $e) {

           die("Cannot connect to DB");

        }
    }


    }
```

This connect, for 2 DB

```
$connect        = new DB(_DB_HOST_, _DB_NAME_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASS_);
$connectSlave   = new DB(_DB_HOST_, _DB_NAME_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASS_);
```

First connect - good, second - Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: DB::$connectSlave

Please help me.

Comment: Your connect variable is a static property of the DB class. This means it is shared among all instances of the DB class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$connect should be an instance variable instead of static (otherwise it's shared between DB instances):

```
public $connect = false;
```

Then use `$this->connect` instead of `self::$connect`. Here's your class:

```
class DB
{
    public $connect = false;
    private $database_host = 'localhost';
    private $database_user = '';
    private $database_pass = '';
    private $database_db = '';
    private $database_type = 'mysql';

    function __construct($database_host, $database_db, $database_user, $database_pass)
    {
        $this->database_host   = $database_host;
        $this->database_db     = $database_db;
        $this->database_user   = $database_user;
        $this->database_pass   = $database_pass;

        if ($this->connect === false) {
            $this->connect();
        }
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $dsn = $this->database_type . ":dbname=" . $this->database_db . ";host=" . $this->database_host;

        try {

            $this->connect = new PDO($dsn, $this->database_user, $this->database_pass, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
            $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            //var_dump(self::$connect);

            if(!$this->connect) {
            die("Cannot connect to DB");    
            }


        } catch (PDOException $e) {

           die("Cannot connect to DB");

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I already did. Remove the "static" keyword at the declaration of $connect, and use $this->connect instead of self::$connect